# How can I remove unnecessary warning messages?

Tags: warning-messages

I updated `Mathematica`,`CdfPlayer` to new Version (9). I made a simple Application in Mathematica 9 and deployed into `CDF`.I get unnecessary messages whenever i open that `CDF` file.

How can I overcome that?

Error Message :

[image]

Comment: sorry for that , I'm using CDF PlayerV 8.0.4 only..

Comment: Since you made the CDF, this might be related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16547/save-notebook-without-including-front-end-version-information

Answer (score 2):

I am nearly sure that you can't.

Constructing a notebook in Mathematica 9, setting explicitly FrontEndVersion to something else than $Version will be ignored and you end up with the default (at least that happened when I tried, on Windows).

Since CDFs are signed, they stop working if you edit them or do anything similar to [Save notebook without including Front End version information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16547/save-notebook-without-including-front-end-version-information)

I think this is all good as it is, since if you want to generate CDFs which should run in the free CDF Player 8, then use Mathematica 8.

And CDFs generated by Mathematica 9 will only run without warning in CDF player 9 (which we all hope will be out soon).

I don't think the warning is unnecessary, since you may very easily construct something in Version 9 which will not run properly in CDF Player 8.