# Save PaletteNotebook without any meta-data

Tags: notebooks, palettes

The SE Uploader is created with

```
CreateWindow[PaletteNotebook[...]]
```

and then I need to save this under the `FrontEnd/Palettes` folder of the `` SETools` `` package so that users get the palette in their menu. I would like to save this without any meta-information like my os, absolute window position/size, or caches. We already have a plethora of related posts:

- [Save notebook without including Front End version information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16547/187)
- [Stop PaletteNotebook from asking to save changes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137790/187)
- [How to save palette positions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123920/187)

I know this is very related to the information we already have, but maybe it's worth asking this separately.

**Is there an easy way to save/export the SE Uploader palette without any meta-information that might break it for others?**

Comment: The first one you linked was also motivated by the image uploader. I do not recall ever finding a great solution to this. Of course, the simple thing to do is to post-process the notebook source and remove the FE version information. This is non-ideal because it makes the cache invalid (you better disable the notebook cache), which slows down the loading of the notebook. But perhaps it's not a big issue for a palette.

Comment: The other thing one can do is to re-save the notebook with the oldest version of Mathematica that you support. This is what I currently do with doc notebooks. I have a small package to automate calling arbitrary older kernel versions through MathLink. Of course, they need to be installed ... so again, not great.

Comment: For the moment, I have deleted the entries manually. I just thought there might have been some progress in making this easier.